# How to profile all web requests to Azure Cloud Service with Application Insights Profiler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cloud-services

I have a question about Application Insights Profiler.

I installed it on the Cloud Service and it works when I add the inline code from the docs:

https://github.com/CawaMS/EnableProfilerForCompute/blob/master/How%20to%20enable%20Application%20Insights%20Profiler%20on%20Azure%20Compute%20resources.md#enable-the-profiler-on-cloud-services-applications

```
using (var operation = client.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("[unique_name_for_your_operation]"))
{
    ProcessQueueMessage(msg);
}
```

But how can I trace all the requests with a profiler for a web role? I can't find any info for several days. The official docs say that for web roles it track all requests automatically:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler-cloudservice#enable-profiler-for-your-azure-cloud-service

> 3. Track requests with Application Insights:
>
> For ASP.Net web roles, Application Insights can track the requests
>   automatically.
>
> For Worker Roles, add code to track requests.

And also the troubleshooting docs describe the App Service problems, not Cloud Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler-troubleshooting?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json

Comment: If it tracks it automatically for web roles then that suggests it should be discover able in Application insights in the portal. Is that not what you are seeing?